# How to find the exact same rows in different columns and insert a new column based on the matching?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two columns like below:

```
col_1                  col_2
--------             -----------
x1                    x2
x3                    x4
x4                    x10
x5                    x5
x7                    x11
```

I want to find out the values of `col_2` exist in `col_1`. The output should be something like below:

```
col_1                  col_2         bool
--------             -----------  -------
x1                    x2           False
x3                    x4           True
x4                    x10          False
x5                    x5           True
x7                    x11          False
```

I have tried following the way to do this: but it creates a new df that only matches the rows:

```
df2 = pd.merge(df['col_1'], df['col_2'], 
               left_on = 'col_1', right_on = 'col_2',
               how='inner', indicator='bool')
```

But it's not producing the output that I exactly want. Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) for check membership:

```
df['bool'] = df['col_2'].isin(df['col_1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `numpy.where(condition, x, y)` by comparing the two column as the condition.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

comparison_column = np.where(df["col1"] == df["col2"], True, False)
df["bool"] = comparison_column
print(df)
```